# React integration testing, how to wait for page to be ready

Tags: reactjs, selenium-chromedriver

We have a web application written with React JS in the frontend and a PHP backend.

We are setting up Selenium integrated testing for the React frontend. In the past when we've done this for PHP applications, it is easy to wait for the page to be loaded before processing the assertions.

However in the React application, the web-browser doesn't actually change pages, instead the React renderer just renders the page differently.

Is there an easy way to tell if Reach is still busy fetching data from the server, and so the tests assertions need to wait?

Comment: I don't know much about `Selenium integrated testing`, but can you implement an event-trigger inside `componentDidMount` method of the last ReactJS component which would mount? When that special event is triggered it means all ReactJS components are mounted.

Comment: I don't think that would work - the components are written to be page agnostic, and which components are going to be on a page can vary based on user preferences.